# Let $n\ge2$ and $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ be positive reals such that $a_1a_2\dots a_n=1$. Use mathematical induction to prove that $a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n\ge n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I'll start by explaining my approach:
First I start by proving the base step ($n=2$)
I get a quadratic equation, after solving for its range, I'm able to solve the base step.

For the latter part, I tried to use the relation ${\rm AP}\ge{\rm GP}$, but I'm not able to prove it using that. I'm new here so I'm not sure how I'm supposed to explain this but I hope it gives an idea.

Is my approach correct or should I try something else?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics! Welcome to MSE! Be sure to format your question using MathJax formatting, otherwise the question maybe poorly received by the community, Refer to the following link: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: Do you mean not able to prove it meaning you're not allowed to, or that there is no solution that way? Because I can think of a way

Comment: It is supposed to mean $AM>GM$?

Comment: @SleepyMusk Welcome to Math SE. FYI, [$a_1a_2\cdots a_n = 1 \implies a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n \geq n$ if $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n > 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/762912/602049) asks basically the same question, but there's a specific stipulation there to *not* use AM-GM.